# How send form to another domain and get response?

Tags: php, forms, api

How i can send form data to another domain and take response?

I try to send it by ajax, but i have error

```
Allow-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

If i send normal html form i cant get response

I need this to make API SMS.

edit:
Here is ajax:

```
$("#submit").click(function(e)
    {
        var postData = $('#form-tab-client').serializeArray();

        $.ajax(
            {
                url : 'https://another_domain_gateway',
                type: "POST",
                data : postData,
                success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                {
                    alert('sucess');
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log(textStatus);
                    console.log(jqXHR);
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                {
                    alert('error');
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                    console.log(textStatus);
                    console.log(jqXHR);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Ajax? Where is ajax plz add

Comment: sounds like a job for CURL but way to few details

Comment: ok i edit, maybe for php i can send form and take response?

Comment: Just send the ajax to your server and then post to their server with your PHP script. CORS may or may not work here given the `destination servers` resource sharing configuration.

Comment: how i can get response from other server? other server give me response for json {"error":"success" etc....}

Answer (score 0):

If you're receiving an error about **Allow-Control-Allow-Origin** then it simply means that CORS is disabled/unavailable to your browser address. If you do not own the target server then there's not much you can do to enable this functionality (and by the looks of it you're targeting an SMS API which you most likely do not own).

What you could do is set up a small back-end API endpoint which takes your request, executes the SMS API request and then sends the response back to the browser. This server would also need CORS enabled, rather than explaining all the steps to enable CORS you can find the information over at http://enable-cors.org/ should you take this route.

Comment: is another way to send form to other domain and take response?

Comment: from your browser there isn't any other way to achieve this.

Comment: maybe like this: http://wezfurlong.org/blog/2006/nov/http-post-from-php-without-curl/ or https://www.madebymagnitude.com/blog/sending-post-data-from-php/ ????

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy if you really must, but in most cases a reverse proxy is the easiest approach.